# What benefits do I get from replaying missions?

Tags: spiral-knights

Spiral Knights recently added missions,  an award system tied to the missions you complete, and an arbitrary "prestige" value that certain missions award you that may or may not (i.e. some does, some doesn't) bring you one step closer to leveling up.

What can I gain from replaying a mission I've already completed?  Can I get the mission rewards and the prestige again?  Just the prestige? Does it count toward leveling up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not get the mission rewards and prestige from replayed missions, however you do get the money and items you found within the missions.
Thus, replaying missions may not be a way to profit from selling the rewards, but it makes farming Materials, Tokens and Crowns much easier by simply being able to make a pure Snarbolax or Jelly King run for example.

Answer (score 0):

You get a reward: prestige. Do a boss level in prestige rank and you get bunch of token boxes.

Comment: Um, no, I don't think you get any prestige from replaying missions.  *Prestige* missions, yes, but only because they reset, and you can't get prestige from playing them more than once between resets, anyway.